# How to add an index by storing an array in LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, local-storage

```
    const getLocation = () => {                                                   //현재 위치 값 가져오는 함수
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, option);
    } else {
        alert("위치정보를 사용할 수 있는 기기가 아닙니다.")
    }
}

function success(position) {
    let loca = localStorage.getItem("user_location");
    if (loca === null) {
        let dis = [];
        let arr = [{
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lon: position.coords.longitude,
            time: position.timestamp
        }];
        localStorage.setItem("user_location", JSON.stringify(arr));
        localStorage.setItem("distance", dis);
    } else {
        loca = JSON.parse(loca);
        localStorage.setItem("user_location", JSON.stringify(loca.concat(
            {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lon: position.coords.longitude,
                time: position.timestamp
            })));

        setstate(loca);
        console.log(state)


    }
}
```

The location value is periodically retrieved every 15 seconds and stored in local storage.
However, not only the new values ​​are stored in the array, but the previously received values ​​are also stored.

```
For example
0: [{1}], -15 seconds
1: [{1}],
2: [{1},{1,2}], -15 seconds
3: [{1}],
4: [{1},{1,2}], 
5: [{1},{1,2},{1,2,3}] -15 seconds 
...
```

I want the newly retrieved value to be stored in a new index. How can I do it?

```
function success(position) {
        let loca = localStorage.getItem("user_location");
        if (loca === null) {
```

My prediction seems to be because I fetch the array (loca) before executing the if statement, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Append existing value with what you get (current value):

```
localStorage.setItem(
  'user_location',
  JSON.stringify([
    ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_location')),
    {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lon: position.coords.longitude,
      time: position.timestamp,
    },
  ])
);
```

Comment: It seems that I misrepresented the example. I'm sorry.

I tried running it as I told you, but the result is the same.

Modified the example!

Comment: Your explanation `0: [{1}], -15 seconds
1: [{1}],
2: [{1},{1,2}], -15 seconds
3: [{1}],
4: [{1},{1,2}], 
5: [{1},{1,2},{1,2,3}] -15 seconds` seems to confuse me. intead represent `0`, `1`, `2` for array index values